# NSS-signtool function failed: security library?

Tags: build, firefox-addon, certificate, code-signing, signing

When trying to sign a firefox extension with this line:

> nss-signtool -k "TestCert" -d .keys/cert_db/ -p "test" -X -Z ./dist/test.xpi ./build/test/

I get the following error, and nothing more:

> signtool: function failed: security library: bad database.

I made the database and installed a certificate using these instructions: https://www.mozdevgroup.com/docs/pete/Signing-an-XPI.html

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: No idea what it means but NSS is generally very hard to use. [`xpisign.py`](https://github.com/nmaier/xpisign.py) is much simpler and might do the job for you (*disclaimer*: it is based on [my blog post](https://adblockplus.org/blog/signing-firefox-extensions-with-python-and-m2crypto)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops... i made some syntax errors... should be "./keys/cert_db" instead of ".keys/cert_db"

I believed that fixed it!

Comment: But does anyone know what that error means? and why it came up for a syntax error?